# can't set Attr as {type, list(type)} when create op in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

seems that `Attr("Tout: {list(type), type}")` is not allowed in tensorflow op creation.

```
F tensorflow/core/framework/op.cc:160] Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (RegisterAlreadyLocked(deferred_[i])) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Unrecognized type string 'type' from Attr("Tout: {type, list(type)}") for Op Py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TensorFlow [`OpDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/32bd3d024f33e920a67a1081bc0ae0048350fdee/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.proto) type system doesn't currently support arguments (or outputs) whose types may be either a list of types or a single type. Instead, you can use `.Attr("Tout: list(type)")` to represent the input (or output) type. If the distinction between a list of tensors and a single tensor is important, you can use an additional `bool`-valued attr to represent that distinction.

Note that if you are using the automatically-generated Python wrappers to invoke your op, and you want this input to accept a single tensor or a list of tensors, you will need to add a custom wrapper function that creates a list as appropriate. This [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/32bd3d024f33e920a67a1081bc0ae0048350fdee/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py#L215) in the standard TensorFlow library does this for `QueueBase.enqueue()` and `QueueBase.enqueue_many()` arguments, which may be a single tensor or a list of tensors.